# Загрузка большого количества уникалных строк в бд

Tags: php, mysql

**Есть 5 таблиц:**

**table_1** ( id, name )

**table_2** ( id, name )

**table_3** ( id, name )

**table_4** ( id, name )

**table_all** ( table_1_id, table_2_id, table_3_id, table_4_id)

Ко мне приходит массив данных в виде:

```
$data = [
    [
        'name_1' => 'Test 1',
        'name_2' => 'Test 2',
        'name_3' => 'Test 3',
        'name_4' => 'Test 4'
    ],
    [
        'name_1' => 'Test 1',
        'name_2' => 'Test 2',
        'name_3' => 'Test 3',
        'name_4' => 'Test 4'
    ],
    [
        'name_1' => 'Test 1',
        'name_2' => 'Test 2',
        'name_3' => 'Test 3',
        'name_4' => 'Test 4'
    ],
    ...
];
```

**Задача:** залить **name_1** в таблицу **table_1** (и так с другими **name**) и вернуть **id**, и эти **id** нужно залить в **table_all**.

Суть в том, что ко мне приходит массив, где этих строк более 10 000, и я беру в каждую из 4 таблиц делаю insert и получаю id, и затем эти все id заливаю в **table_all**, итого для каждого набора данных мне нужно сделать 5 запросов в бд, как мне это все довести до ума?

Comment: Ну поскольку многотабличного INSERT нет, то только так. Вот если бы загружаемые данные были уникальны, последний запрос (на вставку в table_all) можно было бы делать один, а не по запросу на каждый блок.

Comment: Если запись в table_all должна появляться всегда, возможно стоит повесить на первые 4 таблицы триггера, создающие ее автоматически при записи в них